# Allow streaming of large video file to authenticated users with PHP

Tags: php, video-streaming

I have a 4GB .mp4 video I need to allow authenticated users to stream.

I have the video in a directory which is secured via .htaccess like this:

```
Deny from all
```

When a user requests access to the video, I use a PHP script to check for authentication, then send the video like this:

```
<?php

        header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $video . '.mp4"');
        header('Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        ob_clean();
        $wasdownloaded = readfile('video/' . $video . '.mp4');
        if ($wasdownloaded===true){
            Flush();
        }

?>
```

I am using [Floatbox.js](https://floatboxjs.com/) which has built-in (and simple) capability to stream video. I am not tied to using that, though.

I am finding that I can stream 1-3 minutes of the video before it times out, even on a good connection. I would think there are a couple of potential bottlenecks, and not sure where to start:

- Is the "readfile" technique in PHP able to handle a 4GB video? It definitely works to start, but possibly it is too much for the server to handle, especially if the video is placed in memory as it is streaming?
- Do I need a more sophisticated streaming software platform? Floatbox.js works nicely for small videos or YouTube embeds, but it is not designed primarily for video streaming.
- Do I need to look to an outside provider (Vimeo, etc.) to handle streaming, compression, etc.? The issue here is that I don't know if I can authenticate the users as easily, or at all.

Comment: Where are you hosting the video?  Did you set the timeout to 0 in the php file?

Comment: What does your error log show? Per the manual, `readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level().`

Comment: We are hosting the video on a dedicated virtual server that we lease. I did not setup a timeout of 0 in the PHP file. I see "max_execution_time = 30" in my php.ini file, I should just set that to 0? Or can I do this on just my one PHP script instead of the entire website? I have not seen any error messages, the video just quits loading.

Comment: I added set_time_limit(0); to the PHP script that contains the "readfile" bit, that doesn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: Then most likely your virtual server doesn't like the persistent connection and cuts it